<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0xBAADCA11 explanation:<no explanation given> reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Why does the app crash when a CallKit message arrives and the app is woken up? From the online crash log, the crash always occurs at the 7 - second mark from the time of wake - up.
Date/Time:           2024-10-30 17:53:55.3612 -0400
Launch Time:         2024-10-30 17:53:47.9183 -0400

Business:
For a camera app, when a device initiates a call, the app accepts it. If multiple devices make multiple calls and the app receives new messages, it closes the previously unprocessed calls with an end - call operation.
Project setting：

My core code：
config
    func configOptions() {
        // 创建 CXProviderConfiguration
        let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: Constant.APP_NAME)
        providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
        providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        providerConfiguration.maximumCallGroups = 1
        ///支持的处理类型必须要包括下面CXHandle对应的类型，否则点击通话记录不会唤起app
        providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
        providerConfiguration.ringtoneSound = "sound_call.mp3"
        let img = UIImage.gz_image(named: "icon_callkit_logo")
        providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = img?.pngData()
        // 使用 CXProviderConfiguration 创建 CXProvider
        provider = CXProvider(configuration: providerConfiguration)
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

    }

didReceiveIncomingPushWith
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        XLog.info("enter")
        guard type == .voIP else {
            CallKitManager.shared.reportFakeCall(completion: completion)
            return
        }
        XLog.info("type = \(type)")
        guard let dictionaryPayload = payload.dictionaryPayload as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            CallKitManager.shared.reportFakeCall(completion: completion)
            return
        }
        XLog.info("payload = \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
        guard let pushModel = GzPushModel.deserialize(from: dictionaryPayload) else {
            CallKitManager.shared.reportFakeCall(completion: completion)
            return
        }
        guard let typeCall = dictionaryPayload["type"] as? String else {
            CallKitManager.shared.reportFakeCall(completion: completion)
            return
        }
        XLog.info("typeCall = \(typeCall)")
        guard typeCall == "call" || typeCall == "ring" else {
            CallKitManager.shared.reportFakeCall(completion: completion)
            return
        }
        XLog.info("call access")
        endCall()
        reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID(), pushModel: pushModel) { error in
            XLog.error("error = \(String(describing: error))")
            if error == nil {
                XLog.info("completion error \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            completion()
        }
    }

reportIncomingCall
    func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, pushModel: GzPushModel, hasVideo: Bool = true, completion: @escaping ((Error?) -> Void)) {
        XLog.info("enter")
        let pushEventModel = pushModel.pushValue as? GzPushEventModel
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: pushEventModel?.deviceId ?? "aosu")
        update.hasVideo = hasVideo
        let callerName = String(format: GLString("callkit_call_title"), pushEventModel?.deviceName ?? "doorbell")
        update.localizedCallerName = callerName
        update.supportsHolding = false
        update.supportsGrouping = false
        update.supportsUngrouping = false
        self.currentPushModel = pushModel
        self.currentCallUUid = uuid
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion: completion)
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try? audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat)
    }

reportFakeCall
    func reportFakeCall(completion: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
        callUpdate.supportsHolding = false
        callUpdate.supportsGrouping = false
        callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = false
        callUpdate.supportsDTMF = false
        callUpdate.hasVideo = false
        let fakeUUID = UUID(uuidString: "EEEEEEEE-EEEE-EEEE-EEEE-EEEEEEEEEEEE")!
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(
            with: fakeUUID,
            update: callUpdate,
            completion: { [weak self] error in
                completion()
                self?.provider.reportCall(with: fakeUUID, endedAt: nil, reason: .unanswered)
        })
    }

endcall
    func endCall() {
        guard let currentCallUUid else { return }
        let callController = CXCallController()
        // 1. 创建一个结束呼叫的动作
        let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: currentCallUUid)

        // 2. 使用此动作创建一个事务
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endCallAction)

        // 3. 提交事务
        callController.request(transaction) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                XLog.info("Failed to end call: \(error)")
            } else {
                XLog.info("Call ended successfully!")
            }
        }
        
        // 结束音频
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try? audioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    }

Crash log
Incident Identifier: 9BD86D4A-D409-4CD9-83E7-6030770356F0
Distributor ID:      com.apple.AppStore
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             xxx [26230]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/xxx.app/xxx
Identifier:          com.ggggg.ios
Version:             3.4.10 (6315)
AppStoreTools:       16A242d
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:15
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ggggg.ios [1330]

Date/Time:           2024-10-30 17:53:55.3612 -0400
Launch Time:         2024-10-30 17:53:47.9183 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.6.1 (21G93)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    6.00.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 0xbaadca11 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0xBAADCA11 explanation:<no explanation given> reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef2316c8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234ec8 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234de0 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234c20 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65acf5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65ac600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65abcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   GraphicsServices                0x00000001eaff91a8 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a8be5ae8 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3713)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a8c99d98 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5303)
10  xxx                             0x000000010283fe28 main + 100 (main.m:20)
11  dyld                            0x00000001c9d83154 start + 2356 (dyldMain.cpp:1298)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290c4 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290c4 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290c4 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef2316c8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234ec8 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234de0 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234c20 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65acf5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65ac600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65abcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a54ccb5c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a54cc9ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a8bf981c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420 (UIEventFetcher.m:1207)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001a54e3428 __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020302e06c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290d8 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef231644 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae483370 _dispatch_sema4_wait + 28 (lock.c:139)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae483a20 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 132 (semaphore.c:132)
3   aosu                            0x0000000105200960 -[UMNetworkWork postDataToServer:withFile:] + 600
4   aosu                            0x0000000105200668 -[UMNetworkWork postDataWithFile:] + 1896
5   aosu                            0x00000001051ffc84 -[UMNetworkWork main] + 636
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a5421580 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 16 (NSOperation.m:2189)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a541f820 -[NSOperation start] + 648 (NSOperation.m:1406)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a54a4268 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 16 (NSOperation.m:2220)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001a54a3eb4 __NSOQSchedule_f + 172 (NSOperation.m:2231)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae491e5c _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148 (queue.c:570)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae482dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:576)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae4862d8 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 600 (queue.c:321)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae4858f4 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 584 (queue.c:845)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae494894 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392 (queue.c:7136)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae49509c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156 (queue.c:7204)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020302c8f8 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2709)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290cc start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290c4 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef237bcc __ulock_wait + 8 (:-1)
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae4837c4 _dlock_wait + 56 (lock.c:326)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae4834c0 _dispatch_wait_on_address + 140 (lock.c:498)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae483b90 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 56 (semaphore.c:214)
4   libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001af97da38 OS_dispatch_group.wait(wallTimeout:) + 24 (Dispatch.swift:165)
5   aosu                            0x00000001034e72e8 InstallationsProtocol.installationID(completion:) + 616 (Installations+InstallationsProtocol.swift:63)
6   aosu                            0x00000001034e8638 SettingsDownloader.fetch(completion:) + 32 (SettingsDownloadClient.swift:54)
7   aosu                            0x00000001034e8638 protocol witness for SettingsDownloadClient.fetch(completion:) in conformance SettingsDownloader + 32 (<compiler-generated>:48)
8   aosu                            0x00000001034e8638 RemoteSettings.fetchAndCacheSettings(currentTime:) + 1120 (RemoteSettings.swift:61)
9   aosu                            0x00000001034e3014 RemoteSettings.updateSettings(currentTime:) + 8 (RemoteSettings.swift:97)
10  aosu                            0x00000001034e3014 RemoteSettings.updateSettings() + 16 (RemoteSettings.swift:101)
11  aosu                            0x00000001034e3014 SessionsSettings.updateSettings() + 20 (SessionsSettings.swift:81)
12  aosu                            0x00000001034e3014 protocol witness for SettingsProtocol.updateSettings() in conformance SessionsSettings + 24 (<compiler-generated>:78)
13  aosu                            0x00000001034e3014 closure #1 in closure #1 in Sessions.init(appID:sessionGenerator:coordinator:initiator:appInfo:settings:loggedEventCallback:) + 548 (FirebaseSessions.swift:193)
14  aosu                            0x00000001034e6988 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in Sessions.init(appID:sessionGenerator:coordinator:initiator:appInfo:settings:loggedEventCallback:) + 24 (<compiler-generated>:0)
15  aosu                            0x00000001036694dc closure #1 in Promise.then(on:_:) + 224 (Promise+Then.swift:95)
16  aosu                            0x0000000103668e50 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Swift.AnyObject?) -> (@out Any?) + 56 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  aosu                            0x000000010365c8cc __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.18 + 52 (FBLPromise.m:273)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae48113c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae482dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:576)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae494af4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1000 (queue.c:7136)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae49509c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156 (queue.c:7204)
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020302c8f8 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2709)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290cc start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef2316c8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234ec8 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234de0 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234c20 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   aosu                            0x000000010348a944 FIRCLSMachExceptionReadMessage + 56 (FIRCLSMachException.c:192)
5   aosu                            0x000000010348a944 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 104 (FIRCLSMachException.c:168)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020302e06c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290d8 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef2316c8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234ec8 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234de0 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234c20 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65acf5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65ac600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65abcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a66178f8 _legacyStreamRunLoop_workThread + 300 (CFStream.c:1776)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020302e06c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290d8 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef2316c8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234ec8 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234de0 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ef234c20 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65acf5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65ac600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a65abcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a778cc7c +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 384 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1473)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a54e3428 __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020302e06c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002030290d8 thread_start + 8 (:-1)


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000010004005   x1: 0x0000000507000806   x2: 0x0000000200000000   x3: 0x00000c0300000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x00000c0300000000   x6: 0x0000000000000002   x7: 0x00000000ffffffff
    x8: 0xfffffffffffffbbf   x9: 0x0000000000000c03  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000001
   x12: 0x0000000000000c03  x13: 0x00000000007a0af7  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffd1  x17: 0x00000001ae4cb7f8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000000ffffffff
   x20: 0x0000000000000002  x21: 0x00000c0300000000  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000c0300000000
   x24: 0x000000016d5ca7e8  x25: 0x0000000200000000  x26: 0x0000000507000806  x27: 0x0000000507000806
   x28: 0x0000000107000806   fp: 0x000000016d5ca750   lr: 0x00000001ef234ec8
    sp: 0x000000016d5ca700   pc: 0x00000001ef2316c8        cpsr: 0x0
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
        0x102834000 -         0x105e93fff aosu arm64  <218b1d4cb36e344199518883b731ae31> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/aosu
        0x106d1c000 -         0x106d23fff ThingAvLoggerSDK arm64  <636d48c174423d74a609d9cbd037210e> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingAvLoggerSDK.framework/ThingAvLoggerSDK
        0x106d30000 -         0x106d3ffff ThingVideoCodecSDK arm64  <7691d7ab45a83fc1a03045169f106de6> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingVideoCodecSDK.framework/ThingVideoCodecSDK
        0x1073c0000 -         0x1074c3fff ThingAudioEngineSDK arm64  <7a2ae23c70dc3daf91dea7d4e6f3adc0> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingAudioEngineSDK.framework/ThingAudioEngineSDK
        0x107690000 -         0x107897fff ThingCameraSDK arm64  <efaa265bb6a83e458e8c180650f9b47d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingCameraSDK.framework/ThingCameraSDK
        0x107e60000 -         0x108103fff ThingFFmpegWrapper arm64  <ad1f157d2010361b90618dd4b5e46187> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingFFmpegWrapper.framework/ThingFFmpegWrapper
        0x108310000 -         0x10833ffff ThingLottie arm64  <e30426a0898e33bdb914944c178cb521> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingLottie.framework/ThingLottie
        0x1083a8000 -         0x10842ffff ThingMbedtls arm64  <d50e9d4c74593e159cae39052a786975> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingMbedtls.framework/ThingMbedtls
        0x108468000 -         0x108627fff ThingOpenSSLSDK arm64  <3600d4a16d0e3902a65257632f8dbd6c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingOpenSSLSDK.framework/ThingOpenSSLSDK
        0x1086e4000 -         0x108757fff ThingP2PSDK arm64  <6dbbd32f6d7131288070fc95318b299a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ThingP2PSDK.framework/ThingP2PSDK
        0x1087bc000 -         0x10885bfff ffavc arm64  <31e9c7452c383b1f99ec882349e3bf2c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/ffavc.framework/ffavc
        0x1088b4000 -         0x108a7ffff libpag arm64  <d8dc51aaa3c23e0883b260d6339fe4e6> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97D221AE-88FB-43D8-B36E-57DC12CD31AF/aosu.app/Frameworks/libpag.framework/libpag
        0x108f28000 -         0x108f33fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <be553713db163c12aaa48fd6211e48ce> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
        0x1a5405000 -         0x1a5f7afff Foundation arm64e  <d27a6ec5943c3b0e8d158840fd2914f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
        0x1a6559000 -         0x1a6a86fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <76a3b1983c09323e83590d4978e156f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
        0x1a768f000 -         0x1a7a6bfff CFNetwork arm64e  <371394cd79f23216acb0a159c09c668d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
        0x1a87db000 -         0x1aa2fcfff UIKitCore arm64e  <9da0d27355063712b73de0149d74c13c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
        0x1ae47f000 -         0x1ae4c5fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <5f66cdb608a936158c6a4e3b47005495> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
        0x1ae4c6000 -         0x1ae543ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <7135c2c8ba5836368b46a9e6226ead45> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
        0x1af97b000 -         0x1af992ff7 libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64e  <37c324582b943636b0374c8c82c9511f> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDispatch.dylib
        0x1c9d46000 -         0x1c9dd3937 dyld arm64e  <52039c944da13638bd52020a0b5fa399> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x1eaff8000 -         0x1eb000fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <3ebbd576e7d83f69bcb5b9810ddcc90e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
        0x1ef230000 -         0x1ef269fef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <21ee5290d1193c31b948431865a67738> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x203028000 -         0x203034ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <e4a9d6dbf93b3c88bdd185671ec22e2b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF


I don't know how to fix it, but more infos on your crash: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/sigkill look for "0xbaadca11":  0xbaadca11 (3131951633) — pronounced “bad call” The operating system terminated the app for failing to report a CallKit call in response to a PushKit notification.

However, from the crash log, when the app starts, it doesn't reach the place where a CallKit call is reported at all.

Is the CallKit instance listener/manager launched at start of the app? I'm wondering if the configuration happen after you received a call (if that's possible, I don't use CallKit).
